# .gitignore still ignoring removed items

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a standard .gitignore file that I include in every project. One of the lines in there ignores "bin".

It so happens, in this particular project, I actually *want* a /bin directory. I removed "bin" from .gitignore, but git still won't let me add the /bin directory. It still thinks it should ignore it, even though the string has been removed from .gitignore.

All the answers I'm finding are about how to ignore something previously committed, but I'm not finding any info on how to add something previously ignored.

So: How do I tell git to unignore something previously ignored?

Comment: Is there anything in you /bin directory?

Comment: Yes, there are files in /bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Ensure your .gitignore does not ignore the `bin` directory anymore. To confirm you can run `git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others` from the root of your repo to list all the files ignored by git.
- Another way to do the same is if you try add the `bin` directory using `git add` ***without*** giving a `-f` argument, git would complain that the files are currently being ignored. If you do see this message you still have a `.gitignore` somewhere which seems to cause git to ignore the `bin` directory.
- Also remember that git does not version empty directories. You need to have at least a single file under a directory for git to track it under version control. In that case create a dummy file under the `bin` directory and that file say `git add bin/.dummy`. This way you ensure that the `bin` directory is created on a clone or a checkout.

**UPDATE** based on your comments:

- The .gitignore files can be present at multiple directories in the repository to include or exclude rules for different directory levels. From the root of your repo, run `find . -type f -name .gitignore` to see if you have any other gitignore files in your repo.

There is also a global way to specify gitingore using the following git configuration option, check to see if such a config exists in your setup:

```
git config --global --get core.excludesfile
```

Comment: Hmm. Great answer. Unfortunately, none of those suggestions panned out. I wasn't aware of the global gitignore via git config. Seemed like a likely solution, but it turned out that "bin" isn't in there. The git ls-files suggestion returned nothing. There are files in the bin dir. There's only one gitignore in the project.

Comment: @WarrenBenedetto - In addition to looking under `.git/info/exclude`, you might want to look at the following 2 config options `git config --get --local core.excludesfile` and `git config --get --global core.excludesfile` to see if some other file is meant to be used as the gitignore file.

Comment: I figured it out. I had removed bin from .gitignore, but I didn't notice [Bb]in until now. That explains it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have a global git ignore file - in `~/.gitignore` typically. You can check for this with:

```
-> git config core.excludesfile 
/home/andy/.gitignore
```

You can invert the ignore rule, or the simplest solution is to just add the bin files and move on:

```
git add -f bin
git commit -m "Adding my bin files"
```

Comment: The global gitignore is obtained using the global config option `core.excludesfile` and can be anything other than `~/.gitignore` as well ;)

Comment: I just wanted to point out a correction. The first version of your answer (before the edit) did not mention anything about `core.excludesfile`. But now it does not matter, since you've added that part to your answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Note too sure what you mean by it is still 'ignoring' it.  You mean when you type 'git status' the bin/ directory doesn't show up as untracked or modified?

Try explicitly adding it to git perhaps?

```
git add bin/
git commit -m "Adding the bin directory"
```

Comment: $ git add bin/
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
bin
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added

Comment: Using -f works, but I'm still curious why it thinks 'bin' is in .gitignore when it has been removed. Feels like there should be some command to reload/refresh .gitignore or something, but I don't see anything like that.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files has some helpful info.  I would suggest you take a look into your global ignore file.